# Install remote printer fails

Tags: printing

I have a new MacBook laptop and I can not get a remote printer installed.
When I do "Add Printer" it comes up with a screen that lists the remote
printer I want (and a few others), and when I select it finds the
location and driver, but when I hit "Add", it says it is setting up the remote printer, but the printer does not get added.  If I connect
the same printer directly via USB, I can install it.

How can I get the printer recognized?

Comment: We have nothing to work with... what MacBook, what OS, what printer, is it on the supported list at Apple - https://support.apple.com/HT201465 ?

Comment: It's a brand-new MacBook, 12", 2017.  It's running Sierra, as is the Mac to which the printer is connected.  The printer is an HP 1022, and it is supported.  I can remote-print from a Mac Mini on the same network, also running Sierra, but that printer was set up long ago.

Comment: I have the same issue on Catalina `10.15.7 (19H2)`. It used to work.